# How can I auto-size a div for certain elements, but let others overlap it?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I have a website with a modal dialog box containing an input form. The text box at the bottom of the form is set up to use an autocomplete list to suggest options as you type into it. This is provided by a typeahead javascript module.

By default, the typeahead list falls underneath the modal footer:

[image: typeahead is overlapped]

So I edited the css for the containing dev to set the 'overflow' to 'visible'. This allowed the typeahead to overlap the footer, but the div shrunk, because it no longer had to contain all of the content:

[image: div shrinks to almost nothing]

The only way I could think to fix this was to make the height of the div constant, but now I have the problem that the error boxes can push the content into the footer:

[image: validation boxes overlap]

My question is: Is there a way that I can set up the div so that it automatically resizes to fit its usual content (the input boxes and the validation boxes), but allows the suggestion list to overlap the footer?

I have attached the HTML here:

```
<div class="modal-body"  @*Note! This height value will need to be updated if the contents change, it is here to allow the Typeahead list to 
overlap the rest of the div*@ style="height: 345px; overflow: visible">
<!-- Container for top half of objection form -->
<div class="span4 offset2">

    @Html.Partial("OfferDisplay",Model.OfferDisplayModel)

</div>
<div class="span8">
    <form id="rejectionForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" data-ajax-pubsubupdate="RenderPresentOfferOptionsForm">
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.NegotiationSessionId" name="NegotiationSessionId"/>
        <hr />

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RejectionReasonId, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RejectionReasonId, Model.RejectionReasons, new { @class = "input-large" })
                <button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-validation" tabindex="-1" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-ok"></i><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></button>

                <div class="help-block">
                    <p>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RejectionReasonId)</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TargetPrice, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-gbp"></i></span>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TargetPrice, new { @class = "input-medium", style = "width:162px", @data_val_keypressfilter_regex = UIValidationRegularExpressions.NumberKeyPressFilterRegex })
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-validation" tabindex="-1" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-ok"></i><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CompetitorNameId, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <input id="competitorName" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="input-large" style="width: 198px"/>
                </div>

                <button type="button" class="btn pull-right btn-validation" tabindex="-1" disabled="disabled"><i class="icon-ok"></i><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- the real submit button has to be hidden because the button we want to click is outside this div, and the form cannot span both divs -->
        <input id="RejectionFormSubmitButton" type="submit" style="display: none"/>
        <input id="competitorIdField" name="CompetitorNameId" type="hidden"/>
        <input id="showNextOfferInput" type="hidden" value="true" name="ShowNextOffer"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">

<form method="POST" data-ajax-pubsubupdate="RenderOverrideConfirmationForm">
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.NegotiationSessionId" name="NegotiationSessionId" />
    <input type="hidden" value="@Model.SchemeId" name="SchemeId" />
    <button class="btn btn-warning pull-left" type="submit"><i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.OverrideButton)</button>

    <input id="cancelButton" class="btn" type="button" value="@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.CancelButton)"/>

    @if (Model.OfferDisplayModel.Offer.IsFinalOffer)
    {
        <input id="submitAndCloseButton" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SubmitAndCloseButton)"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <input id="rejectAndShowNextOffer" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SubmitButton)"/>
    }
</form>
```

Comment: Are the rest of your elements in the container floating? Are they even inside the container? Some code would help.

Comment: I've uploaded the HTML source of the page. I don't think any of the elements are floating, woult this mean that their associated CSS has 'float: left/right'?

Comment: Yes. Unless the elements inside the container are floating or positioned absolute/fixed, the container should expand to the include the elements. Can you attach your css too?

Comment: It's not feasible to attach the css - we're using a version of the Twitter Bootstrap framework (slightly modified for internal use), and it's CSS files are enormous.

None of the elements have float: left or float: right applied to them, and all of them appear to have position: static.

I can get the div to automatically size, but then this automatically sizes to the dropdown list too, which I don't want to happen. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use the "z-index" css property.

Comment: No. `z-index` does not work if the overflow is hidden.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this out and unfortunately this doesn't work.